# VS Code - How to make down arrow move down instead of navigating suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can see in VS Code that you get suggestions when you type:

[image]

Pressing the down key currently navigates these suggestions.

I would like to move my cursor up and down using the arrow keys. Currently I have to press escape every few seconds to achieve this.

Can I reconfigure what keys can be used to navigate these suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `selectNextSuggestion` and `selectPrevSuggestion` commands in the keybindings:

[image]

Note that there are two for each direction. You can unbind the ones that use only the arrow keys - that way if you do ever want to scroll the suggestions using the arrows keys still, you can do so by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.  By unbinding the ones that use just the arrows keys, you can achieve what you are after.

Comment: Amazing thanks, I changed it to shift+up/down. Ctrl didn't work for me, possibly because I have the sublime key bindings installed.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, I was facing this issue after updating vs code